# Given list of 10 statement , 8th statement is "Exactly 8 statements in list are false" . Then what is complement of 8th statement

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm confused during solving this question means if 8th statement is false then what the 8th statement became ?

does it became

**1.Exactly 8 statements in list are true.**

*or*

**2.This is not the case that "Exactly 8 statements in list are false" 
then it means this is case of less than 8 statements are true or more than 8 statements are true but not exactly 8"**

Which one is correct  ?

Comment: The second one is the negation.

Comment: Here's a possible compliment: That is a very nice statement!

Comment: @fqq : Good one, +1 for you. Heh. For OP's benefit, I point out that "compliment" and "complement" have very different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of a statement is a statement that is [true whenever the original is false, and vice versa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation)

Whenever exactly 8 statements are true, your original statement is true, and whenever any number other than 8 statements are true, your original statement is false.

Thus, the complement of the original statement is your second option, as it is false when the number of true statements = 8 and true otherwise, the exact opposite (or complement) of the original statement